# What is a "2 character marker" in pal?

Tags: calendar, pal

What does a "2 character marker" mean in the text calendar pal?

The help for this program is scanty. Is there a way to get more detailed information? Does this program use all the same conventions as gcal? Can I learn it just by reading gcal's documentation?